# 500 Internal Server Error heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, google-places-api

По нажатию кнопки получаю список ближайших больниц, но на heroku дает ошибку 500.

`check.html`

```
<form action="/check" method="POST">
    <button type="check" class="btn btn-primary">Nearest Hospitals</button>   
</form>
<div class="box">
   {% for place in places %}
        <p>{{ place.name }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`python`

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
import geocoder

g = geocoder.ip('me')
lt_lg = g.latlng

lt = lt_lg[0]
lg = lt_lg[1]

@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    API_KEY = 'API_KEY'

    google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY) 

    query_result = google_places.nearby_search( 
            lat_lng ={'lat': lt, 'lng': lg}, 
            radius = 5000, 
            types =[types.TYPE_HOSPITAL]) 

    if query_result.has_attributions: 
        print (query_result.html_attributions)

    for place in query_result.places:
        return render_template('check.html', places=query_result.places)
```

Полез в логи, там такая ошибка. Как решить, может кто сталкивался. Спасибо.

```
GooglePlacesError: Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=36.808%2C-76.0284&type=hospital&radius=1000&key=MY_KEY&language=en&sensor=false failed with response code: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

Comment: Гугл вам ясным языком говорит: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, слишком много запросов.

Comment: @ГеннадийП суть в том, что на heroku я не делал запросов, как загрузил, после одного раз ошика вышла, до этого на locahost все делал

Comment: Ну, скорее всего с этого же айпишника с которого выходит ваше приложение в интернет делали запросы, поэтому и срабатывает ограничение.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, только что с другим API попробовал. Тоже самое.